# How to change the size of a column in latex

Tags: tables, tabularx

I want to adjust the width of my column in Latex because the last column as it shown in screenshot need more area. Is there any solution to change the size in a way that the table does not take the whole page.
I tried to give the attribute with cm {3cm} but it doesn't work.
[image]

This is my code:

```
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}

\tcbset{tab1/.style={fonttitle=\bfseries\large,fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=red!75!black,colbacktitle=Salmon!40!white,
coltitle=black,center title,freelance,frame code={
\foreach \n in {north east,north west,south east,south west}
{\path [fill=red!75!black] (interior.\n) circle (3mm); };},}}

\tcbset{tab2/.style={enhanced,fonttitle=\bfseries,fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=red!50!black,colbacktitle=Salmon!40!white,
coltitle=black,center title}}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[tab2,tabularx={X||Y|Y|Y|Y}]
Plugin & Aliases     & Version    & Coverage    & Primary functionality      \\\hline\hline
encoda   & converter & v0.109.2 &  87\% & Convert documents between file formats \\\hline
jesta & node, javascript, js & v1.8.1 &  83\% &  Compile, build and execute documents that use JavaScript \\\hline
rasta  & R & v0.10.2 &  84\% &  Compile, build and execute documents that use R  \\\hline
pyla   & Python & v0.3.1 & 87\% & Compile, build and execute documents that use Python \\\hline
jupita & Jupyter & v0.2.4 &  96\% &  Execute documents that use Jupyter kernels  \\\hline
dockta & Docker & v0.25.0 &  79\% &  Build Docker images for executable documents  \\\hline
nixtata & Nix & v0.1.2 &  14\% &  Build Nix environments for executable documents  
\end{tcolorbox}
```

Comment: `tabularx={l||>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{2cm}|r|r|Y}` should work.

Comment: What does "change the size in a way that the table does not take the whole page" refer to in this context? Do you want to make your table narrower than it currently is or do you just want to make sure, the table is not as tall as it currently is?

Comment: @leandriis thanks for your answer, thats mean to make the last column (Primary functionality) more larger so it will be not needed to return to the next line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `tabularx={X||Y|Y|Y|Y}` you basically made all 5 columns equally wide. To make your table occupy less space by reducing the amount of wasted space, you can use a simple `l` type column instead of `X` for the first column. Analogously you can replace the `Y` column type you used for columns 3 and 4 with  simple `r` type columns. In order to make the second column narrower while still keeping the automatic linebreaks and the right alignment, you can use `>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{2cm}` instead of this specific `Y`, while you keep the `Y` column type for the last column. Combined, this should result in `tabularx={l||>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{2cm}|r|r|Y}` and a table with less wasted space.

Comment: Thanks, it works ! there is only a small problem, the table is jumped on the top of page, I think it is because the rest size of page is not enough!

Comment: What does "jumped on the top of page" mean here? Please provide a complete and compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get.

Comment: Oh sorry, I am new here, It is mean that the tabular is not positionned in the expected placed (direct after the text), but it has changed his position on the top of the page and before the text

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour with the code you provided so far. By default, a `tcolorbox` does not float (see page 79 of the tcolorbox documentation) and since you did not specify and float placement paramenters, this should not happen. Therefore, please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134144) and ask a [follow-up questions](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2117)

Comment: OK thanks anyway